# Intune App Protection - User group can be assigned multiple policies

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, intune

We are trying out the Intune Graph APIs for App Protection. We have noticed that a user group can be assigned to multiple App Protection Policies. When a user group is assigned multiple policies, which policy takes  precedence?

Answer (score 1):

Managed app policy conflicts are resolved setting-by-setting to create a net effective policy. The more protection setting wins.

For example consider PolicyA and PolicyB deployed to the same group and app.

PolicyA - pinRequired:**false**, encryptAppData:**true**

PolicyB - pinRequired:**true**, encryptAppData:**false**

Effective policy - pinRequired:**true**, encryptAppData:**true**

Thanks

Alemeshet Alemu (MSFT)

Comment: Does this mean that the most restrictive setting of all policies combined apply?

Comment: Conflicting policies get compared setting by setting. The most secure of the setting values is picked. That forms the net effective policy. In the effective (applied) policy example I mentioned earlier, pinRequired:true came from PolicyB and encryptAppData:true came from PolicyA.